# Post current post type to my Ajax

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, javascript, rest-api, api

I have two files, alpine js and a ajax, i want to get my current post type from wordpress with

```
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
$postType = get_queried_object();
```

$args = array(
'post_type'      => $post_type,
'post_status'    => 'publish',
);

and have that pass to my ajax so the post type that is filtered and default is depending on what post type i am currently on.

the code bellow is originally from this tutorial that i have been following, it works fine for a single post type but wish to inject the current post type into the ajax depending on post type.

**Js**

```
    import Alpine from 'alpinejs'


Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL) => ({
    posts: "",
    limit: 10,
    category: null,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,

    filterPosts(id) {
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.fetchPosts();
    },

    fetchPosts() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
        formData.append("offset", this.offset);
        formData.append("limit", this.limit);

        if (this.category) {
            formData.append("category", this.category);
        }

        fetch(adminURL, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            this.posts = res.posts;
        });
    }
}));
 
window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.start()
```

**Ajax**

```
?php
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');

function filterPosts()
{
    $response = [
        'posts' => "",
    ];

    $filter_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    if ($_POST['limit']) {
        $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['limit'];
    }

    if ($_POST['category']) {
        $filter_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
    }

    $filter_query = new WP_Query($filter_args);

    if ($filter_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($filter_query->have_posts()) : $filter_query->the_post();
            $response['posts'] .= load_template_part('/template-parts/posts-filter/single-post');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
```

Comment: yeah, just read though. will update so its clear. apologies

Comment: Do you mean you need to get data for all custom post types?

Comment: Feel free to post your own solution too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the current post type to your AJAX request, you need to modify your JS to include the post type information in the AJAX request. You can achieve this by adding the `post type` as a parameter when calling the `filterPosts()` function

**JS**

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

Alpine.data("filterPosts", (adminURL, postType) => ({
    posts: "",
    limit: 10,
    category: null,
    showDefault: true,
    showFiltered: false,

    filterPosts(id) {
        this.showDefault = false;
        this.showFiltered = true;
        this.category = id;
        this.fetchPosts(postType); // Pass post type to fetchPosts function
    },

    fetchPosts(postType) { // Add postType parameter
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", "filterPosts");
        formData.append("offset", this.offset);
        formData.append("limit", this.limit);
        formData.append("post_type", postType); // Include post type in form data

        if (this.category) {
            formData.append("category", this.category);
        }

        fetch(adminURL, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            this.posts = res.posts;
        });
    }
}));

window.Alpine = Alpine;
Alpine.start();
```

**Ajax**

```
// The AJAX function
add_action('wp_ajax_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filterPosts', 'filterPosts');

function filterPosts()
{
    $response = [
        'posts' => "",
    ];

    $filter_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => isset($_POST['post_type']) ? $_POST['post_type'] : 'post', // Use the post type received from AJAX request
    );

    if ($_POST['limit']) {
        $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['limit'];
    }

    if ($_POST['category']) {
        $filter_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
    }

    $filter_query = new WP_Query($filter_args);

    if ($filter_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($filter_query->have_posts()) : $filter_query->the_post();
            $response['posts'] .= load_template_part('/template-parts/posts-filter/single-post');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

Comment: solved it a few days back myself, but this is very close to how i solved it so accepting this answer.

Comment: Where do you get the post type value on the page though? I thought that was part of the problem.

Comment: I actually get it from the dom using js

Comment: @Rup I use JS to get it from the dom, then load into my php, when im free will update my question with the solution I have

Answer (score 1):

Hi please replace your ajax function like this

```
    function filterPosts()
{
    $show_post_types = get_post_types();
    $post_type_array = array();

  foreach ($show_post_types  as $pt) {
    array_push($post_type_array, $pt);

  }
    $response = [
        'posts' => "",
    ];

    $filter_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' =>  $post_type_array
    );

    if ($_POST['limit']) {
        $filter_args['posts_per_page'] = $_POST['limit'];
    }

    if ($_POST['category']) {
        $filter_args['cat'] = $_POST['category'];
    }

    $filter_query = new WP_Query($filter_args);

    if ($filter_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($filter_query->have_posts()) : $filter_query->the_post();
            $response['posts'] .= load_template_part('/template-parts/posts-filter/single-post');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
```

Comment: I don't think that solves it? That would load all post types, not just the one matching the current page

Comment: (unless I'm misreading your change: can you explain what you have changed please?)

Comment: Yes this is suppose to load all post types. I misunderstood the question.